# Как можно предотвратить распространение стилей на все вложенные элементы?

Tags: css

Как предотвратить распространение стилей на все вложенные элементы?

```
.extend_test{
    background: #972b2b;
    color: slateblue; 
}
```

```
<div class="extend_test">
    тест extend 1
    <div>
        тест extend 2
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Не добавляйте слово "правильно" в заголовок. Ответ и так будет подразумевать "правильный" способ.

Comment: @VenZell дело в том что есть варианты как это можно реализовать совершенно не правильно, деструктивно,  меня интересует мнение профессионала в этом вопросе. Поэтому ключевое слово тут "правильно".

Comment: В данном вопросе невозможны какие либо деструктивные советы, поскольку возможный способ один-единственный из-за самого определения и назначения CSS

Comment: @VenZell мне кажется что там несколькими способами можно это реализовать. Я тогда пока подожду, может кто-нибудь еще что-нибудь скажет по этому поводу.

Comment: @VenZell Да, спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Единственный способ — это сбрасывать отнаследованные значения на потомках на значения по умолчанию, которые могут варьироваться от браузера к браузеру.

> Применение CSS к документам HTML основано на принципах *наследования*
>   и *каскадирования*. [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS#.D0.9D.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5._.D0.9A.D0.B0.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5._.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.82.D1.8B_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.B9_CSS.).

Comment: а может быть как то с помощью селекторов управлении вложенности елементов?

Comment: Нет, стили будут наследоваться на всех потомков, если свойство наследуемое. Например, `float` наследоваться не будет, а вот `color` - да, но с оговорками.

Comment: Можно с помощью селекторов ограничить область распространения стиля, но тогда мне придется добавить еще один div. Может это будет лучше?

Comment: Вы можете уточнить селектор, но не ограничить область распространения. Если свойство наследуемое, оно будет наследоваться "до упора".

Comment: Не захотел описывать все тут, решил создать отдельный вопрос, который сопутствует этому вопросу. Что скажите?  - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485032/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B

Comment: вот еще способ, как можно ограничить распространения стиля, на вложенные элементы.Что скажите?  https://jsfiddle.net/1skcgcpr/3/

Comment: Увы, вы ошибаетесь. table не вложен в h1, поэтому и распространения нет. Оберните содержимое h1 в span - текст останется красным. Сработает наследование.

Comment: вот сейчас почти тоже самое, table не вложен в h1,  и происходит распространения стиля - https://jsfiddle.net/1skcgcpr/10/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34700/discussion-between-venzell-and--).

Comment: Вы заблуждаетесь. Потомки (вложенные элементы) `.special2` будут наследовать желтый цвет. `.special1` не становится желтым, потому что не он является целью... Этот пример не противоречит моим словам.

Comment: я ничего и не написал по этому поводу. Я же удалил почти сразу, свой комментарий.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ждём [all](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all) с [revert](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-revert-value)'ом:

   ```
   all: revert;
   ```

   Теоретически, на данный момент поддержка только у Safari 9+ (и то не всех).
2. С чуть более хорошей поддержкой [initial](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-initial-value):

   ```
   all: initial;
   ```

   Поддержка FF27+, Chrome 37+.
   Из-за `all` отпадает Edge 12+ и более старые версии Хрома и FF.

   К тому же, там несколько неожиданные эффекты наблюдаются.
3. Shadow dom сам по себе изолирует стили.
4. На данный момент самый нормальный способ - явно переопределять стили.
5. Можно было бы предложить комитету `!noinherit` по аналогии с `!important` :)