# Как работают "Дочерние селекторы"?

Tags: css

Если я правильно понял метод работы дочерних селекторов, то то, что написано по нижеприведенной ссылке, не работает.

Стиль распространяется на всех потомков, хотя, судя по описанию, он должен распространяться только на детей, а не на внуков или правнуков.

[Источник](http://vvz.nw.ru/Lessons/CSS/selectors.htm)

Вот пример:

```css
table.special td>h1 {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<table  class="special">
  <tr>
    <td><h1>Test Selector 1</h1>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h1>Test Selector 2</h1>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/1skcgcpr/

Comment: вот здесь посмотрите - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568859/why-doesnt-table-tr-td-work-when-using-the-child-selector

Comment: И что же не так в твоём примере? Два дочерних красных заголовка.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, вы поняли неправильно.
Рассмотрим такой пример:

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="child level-1">
    Потомок 1-го уровня
    <div class="child level-2">Потомок 2-го уровня</div>
  </div>
</section>

/* Случай А */
.container > .child {
  color: red;
}

/* Случай Б */
.container .child {
  color: red;
}
```

В случае А правило **назначается** на потомка первого уровня и **наследуется** потомком 2-го.
В случае Б правило **назначается** на потомков всех уровней.

Более точные пояснения:

В первом случае, чтобы изменить стили потомка второго уровня, достаточно просто к нему обратится по уникальному селектору, чтобы перезаписать стили, поскольку он не попадает в целевую выборку, а его собственный селектор по умолчанию имеет вес равный 0.

```css
.container > .child {
  color: red;
}
.level-2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="child level-1">
    Потомок 1-го уровня
    <div class="child level-2">Потомок 2-го уровня</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Во втором случае, чтобы изменить стили потомка второго уровня придется назначить селектор, вес которого **не меньше**, чем у предыдущего правила, поскольку элемент попадает в целевую выборку.

```css
.container .child {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/* Так не сработает */
.level-2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="child level-1">
    Потомок 1-го уровня
    <div class="child level-2">Потомок 2-го уровня</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Чтобы заработал второй случай, увеличим вес селектора

```css
.container .child {
  color: red;
}
/* Вес селектора не меньше, чем в предыдущем правиле */
.container .level-2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="child level-1">
    Потомок 1-го уровня
    <div class="child level-2">Потомок 2-го уровня</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 5):

Всё работает в соответствии с документацией. В вашем правиле выбираются все потомки `td` (включая "внуков" и "правнуков") таблицы с классом `special`, а уже у них - только прямые.

Можете проверить на правиле `table.special>tr>td>h1 {...}`

Comment: Судя из описания, должны выбираться только дети, а не их внуки и правнуки, вот смотрите  - В ряде случаев нас интересуют не все "потомки" некоего структурного элемента, но лишь непосредственные - не "внуки" или "правнуки", а только "дети" (child). Для указания того, что правило стиля относится только к непосредственному потомку, в селекторе используется символ ">".

Comment: Читайте документацию и написанное правило внимательнее: вы выбираете таблицу `special`, далее выбираете всех потомков `td`, в том числе тех, которые находятся в дочерней для `special` таблице. И только теперь у всех выбранных `td` ищутся прямые потомки `h1`.

Comment: Я понял Вас, спасибо.  Но обратите внимание что  написано из вышеприведённой ссылки.  Цитата: В ряде случаев нас интересуют не все "потомки" некоего структурного элемента, но лишь непосредственные - не "внуки" или "правнуки", а только "дети" (child). Для указания того, что правило стиля относится только к непосредственному потомку, в селекторе используется символ ">".   А на самом деле в моём правиле как Вы и написали, выбираются все потомки  td (включая "внуков" и "правнуков") . То есть, то что там написано, в вышеприведенной ссылки не верно?

Comment: Если бы у вас было `table.special>tr>td>h1 {...}`, то выбирались бы только `td` из таблицы `special`, а у вас между `table.special` и `td` стоит пробел, вы же понимаете, что он означает?

Comment: пробел - селектор потомков,  применяет стиль к элементу, который является вложенным . Просто я хотел у Вас спросить, то что там( по вышеприведенной ссылке)  написано, является дезинформацией? Ведь так?

Comment: да, в абзаце про дочерние селекторы там бредовый пример

Comment: Еще раз, спасибо.

Comment: такая формулировка не работает table.special>tr>td>h1 {...}    https://jsfiddle.net/1skcgcpr/27/

Comment: `table.special>tbody>tr>td>h1 {color: red;}` https://jsfiddle.net/v8rp11qq/

Answer (score 3):

В вашем примере, обе надписи покрасились в красный, т.к. обе подпадают под понятие "дочерние" т.е. h1 является дочкой td. 
У вас или всё работает, или ничего не работает если старый браузер (ie8 например)

Comment: Судя из описания, должны выбираться только дети, а не их внуки и правнуки, вот смотрите  - В ряде случаев нас интересуют не все "потомки" некоего структурного элемента, но лишь непосредственные - не "внуки" или "правнуки", а только "дети" (child). Для указания того, что правило стиля относится только к непосредственному потомку, в селекторе используется символ ">".